# AttributeError: The layer "input_4" has multiple inbound nodes, with different output shapes

Tags: python, docker, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I am getting below error."AttributeError: The layer "input_4" has multiple inbound nodes, with different 
      output shapes. Hence the notion of output shape is ill-defined for the layer". Use 
      get_output_shape_at(node_index) instead".

The code works perfectly fine without running on a Docker container. I have two 
 docker containers on both docker containers I have the same version TensorFlow 
 version 2.1.0 and Keras 2.2.4-tf. However, on the previous system, I ran the 
 code on a windows machine TensorFlow version 1.12.0 and 2.1.6-tf Thanks, help is highly appreciated
 I am running TensorFlow in a docker container using this[1](https://qiita.com/yakigac/items/f05de062fb96650e8d1e) tutorial. Code for Docker file is given 
 below.

Docker file

```
FROM tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-py3

RUN pip install -q keras

RUN pip install prettytable

RUN pip install pillow
```

Python Code

```
import numpy as np
from keras.applications.vgg19 import decode_predictions
from tensorflow.python.keras.models import load_model
from prettytable import PrettyTable
import time
from keras import backend as K
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.python import keras
import time

model_2=load_model('model_2.h5',compile=False)
model_2.summary()

predictions1= np.load('predictions_result.npy')
times=[]
def profiler(model):
   layer_input = keras.layers.Input(batch_shape=model.get_layer('input_4').get_input_shape_at(0))
   x = layer_input
   t = PrettyTable( ['Layer', 'Latency (milliseconds)', 'Output (bytes)'] )
   for layer in model.layers:
      x = layer( x )
    # input and output of layer
      result = 1
      output_shape_list = []
      for i in layer.output_shape[1:]:
        result = result * i
        output_shape_list.append( i )

    intermediate_model = keras.Model( layer_input, x )
    start = time.time()
    intermediate_model = intermediate_model.predict(predictions1)
    np.save('predictions_result', intermediate_model)
    end = time.time() - start
    print(end)
    times.append(end)

    def convert_bytes(result):
        for x in ['bytes', 'KB', 'MB', 'GB', 'TB']:
            if result < 1024.0:
                return "%3.1f %s" % (result, x)
            result /= 1024.0
        return result
    t.add_row([type( layer ).__name__, round( end*1000, 2 ),  convert_bytes( result*4 )])
 print(t)

profiler(model_2)
print("Total Latency(milliseconds):", round(sum(times*1000),2))
tmp=np.zeros((1,28,28,512))

for i in range(0,1):
  tmp[i,:,:,:]=predictions1[i,:]

predictions2 = model_2.predict(tmp)
label_vgg19 = decode_predictions(predictions2)
print ('label_vgg19 =', label_vgg19)
```

Comment: This is a version mismatch: check the version that you are running the code outside the docker image and the version inside. They'll likely be different and the api changed between them.

Comment: Hi, @Yuri-M-Dias I have two docker containers on both docker containers I have the same version TensorFlow version 2.1.0 and Keras 2.2.4-tf. However, on the previous system, I ran the code on a windows machine TensorFlow version 1.12.0 and 2.1.6-tf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue arises in the below line

```
`for i in layer.output_shape[1:]:'
```

Fixed by

```
shape=layer.get_output_at( 0 ).get_shape().as_list()
for i in shape[1:]:
  result = result * i
```